# What are limitations of proofs by contrapositive?

Tags: logic, fake-proofs

If P then Q. Then we can say if not Q then not P, right?

Now we will say that P is an even number and Q is a number such when it's multiplied by itself the result is a positive number.

We will use contrapositive - Then it means that if it's not Q then it's not P.  Because not P is not an even number so it's odd.

But the square of an odd number is a positive number so it's Q.  We now have if not Q then Q. How it's then Q and not Q at the same time?

Maybe an example itself is not valid but I want to know if there's something that I should prove before using contrapositive statements in a proof?

Comment: The implication $\mathrm{not} Q \Rightarrow Q$ is correct since $Q$ is always true.

Comment: The problem is that even/odd only applies to integers.  So, 'not even' can be taken to mean any complex number that is not an even integer.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks! That's is exactly what I don't get -I'm reading about Brouwers fixed point theorem.  Where he is proving - If there is no continuous retraction of the disk to its boundary then every continuous map from the disk to itself has a fixed point. But not directly. Instead, he proves - Given a continuous endomap of the disk with no fixed points, one can construct a continuous retraction of the disk to its boundary.  How does he know that Q is not always true?

Comment: He doesn't know $Q$ is not always true.  He just assumes $Q$ is not true, then shows that $P$ would not be true.

Comment: @J126 Thank you for your comments - It's clear now.